# .Net Winfoms WebBrowser control - When content loaded from Stream, how to permit submit operation?

Tags: winforms, visual-studio, webbrowser-control

I am using the WebBrowser control on a Windows Forms application in Visual Studio 2010 - targeting .Net framework 3.5.

I have loaded the contents of the WebBrowser control via setting the **DocumentStream** property. The stream content is from the response to an Http (POST) request  to a third party web page which is called in code using the HttpWebRequest object. We need to use the POST request verb type. The form is populated with data based on the request parameters.

Within the Windows application, the user needs to fill out a few additional text fields and then submit. Having been loaded via the stream, the page has no knowledge of full url of the original page. Therefore the submit fails (displays the name of the page in the WebBrowser control).

**Is there any way to give the control the full path to the document such that the Submit operation will have the correct context**?  Setting WebBrowser.Url  property does not work as this simply results in navigation to the page without the data displayed as it is not passed any parameters.

Below is the code (so far):

```
//Class to call website to make http post
var webBridge = new WebCallHandler();
//Make the request. Response returned as string
var result = webBridge.MakeHttpRequest();

//Get string as stream
var byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(result);
var stream = new MemoryStream(byteArray) { Position = 0 };
//webBrowser1.Url = new Uri(URL);
webBrowser1.DocumentStream = stream;
//Need to set the context of the page like "http://example.com/somepage.aspx"
var dom = webBrowser1.Document.DomDocument;
```

Comment: Could you replace all relative URLs with absolute URLs (via DOM operations)?

Comment: Hi Kevin. Thanks for the comment. I am not sure where I should be doing this. But your prompt has helped. I think I have solved it.I searched the string for the form element action attribute. This only showed the name of the page received from the httpWebRequest. I modified the string prepending it with the full url. It workd. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have filled the `result` variable (which seems to be a string), you should rather easily be able to modify the contents.

Using e.g. [Regular Expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) or [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) to search for the

```
<form ... action="relative-url" ...
```

and replace it with

```
<form ... action="http://somedomain.com/relative-url" ...
```

then pass it to the `DocumentStream` property of your browser.

Comment: Shot Kevin. This is pretty much what I have done - based on your prompt. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I searched the string being returned from the HttpWebrequest for the **form element action attribute**. This only showed the name of the page received from the httpWebRequest. I modified it in code to be the full url.

Thanks for your comment Kevin. This was the prompt that helped.